# Get file from Folder in Python

Tags: python, url, error-handling, anaconda

The issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2369) too.

I have code like:

```
from keras.datasets.data_utils import get_file

path = get_file('babi-tasks-v1-2.tar.gz', origin='http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/babi/tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz')
tar = tarfile.open(path)
```

When I put the original file location (as the origin above) which is my Downloads folder;

```
/home/xxxxxx/Downloads/tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: /home/xxxxxx/Downloads/tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz
```

How to resolve the issue as the file location is actually correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message suggests that your library requires a resource type at the beginning of the URL. Try specifying your path like this:

```
file:/home/xxxxxx/Downloads/tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function *get_file* seems to take an **url address as a argument** and not an absolute path.

Could you give us more details about this function ?

Comment: Can you copy-paste the code of your function "get_file" ? Does it come from a module ?

Comment: This should probably be posted as a comment

Comment: @Farhan.K Yes, but I can't because the reputation should be at least 50 ...